# Problem creating table, duplicate column in query

Tags: postgis, sql, pgrouting

I am trying to create the following table, but when I execute the query I get the SQL status: 42701, which refers to a duplicate column error (cost column). However, when I run the statement without the first line, the query is executed without problem. How can I solve this?

```
CREATE TABLE lineas_10km AS
WITH DD as (
    SELECT * from pgr_drivingDistance(
        'select id, source, target, cost from red_corta',
            ARRAY (SELECT v.id 
        from clues_3_pocos as h,
            LATERAL (SELECT * from red_corta_vertices_pgr as n
        order by h.geom <-> n.the_geom limit 1) as v), 10000
        )
), dd_lineas as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM  red_corta w, DD d
    WHERE d.node = w.target
)
SELECT * from dd_lineas;
```

Comment: There's a `cost` column in both `DD` and `red_corta` - `SELECT * FROM` a join of both will add both to the result table. You will have to explicitly list all columns and alias a `cost` column in one of your `SELECT`s.

Comment: @geozelot Thanks!!  I wasn't aware of that!